# Javascript IF statement

Tags: javascript, php, calendar, google-calendar-api

Hi I have this section of code which works fine and displays two calendars into one calendar. I also have a `php` variable `$login_session` which contains the user who is logged in email address.

Any idea on how I would display `example@hotmail.com` calendar

(Pseudo code)

```
IF $login_session == "example2@hotmail.com" 

ELSE $login_session == "example3@hotmail.com"
```

display the `en.uk#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com` calendar? Can this even be done?

Any help is appreciated

```
googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyDcnW6WejpTOCffshGDDb4neIrXVUA1EAE',
    eventSources: [
    {
        googleCalendarId: 'example@hotmail.com',
    },
    {
    googleCalendarId: 'en.uk#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com'
    }
        ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if ($login_session == "B.Barry@nhs.org") {
    $calendar = "example@hotmail.com";
} else {
    $calendar = 'en.uk#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com';
}
?>
googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyDcnW6WejpTOCffshGDDb4neIrXVUA1EAE',
    eventSources: [
    {
        googleCalendarId: '<?php echo $calendar; ?>',
    }
],
```

Comment: But wouldn't that just display both the calendars still? I only want one calendar to be displayed depending on the $login_session.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. It has nothing in the `if` statement that says what you want done when the variable matches different things.

Comment: Sorry I'll try better to explain it. Basically if $login_session = for example "B.Barry@nhs.org" then I want the calendar 'example@hotmail.com' to be displayed. if $login_session = for example "C.Carrot@nhs.org" then I want the other calendar to be displayed.

Comment: The solution that @Barmar is giving would work for that scenario. Rembmer, the PHP is going to be parsed and rendered before the JS picks it up.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I wanted!